# Not able to find Product Comments Module - PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: php, comments, prestashop, product, prestashop-1.7

I want to enable the product review feature in my PrestaShop 1.7 installation but I am not able to do that as the module (i.e. Product Comments) responsible for this feature is not there in PrestaShop 1.7.

Has it being built into PrestaShop? Or there is some additional setting for it?

Answer (score 1):

Product Comments module was not yet built into PrestaShop 1.7

Comment: why not? I have a module depending on this one in PS 1.6 and now I cannot make it compatible for 1.7 because of this stupid mistake.